# How to apply multiple transforms to the same element

Tags: css, animation, transform

I have an image of triangle which I use to create a mosaic of triangles.
This image is rotated with transform (rotate) and put in a grid layout.
I need to animate the rows of the layout to slide from different direction to their final position and i have used transform (translate).
My problem is that the animation start with the image in their original orientation and not with the rotated one.
How can I animate the rotated image?

See the allegated image.
https://gifyu.com/image/7lbW

EDIT
Here you can find my code, I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but right now I need this to work if possible.

```css
#loader-container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 12vw; 
  max-width: 830px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.top-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 4vw;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 500px;
  right: 10%;
  margin: 0.25vw;
}
.top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.triangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.blue {
  background-image: url("https://www.hiboucoop-staging.org/wbo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/blue.gif");
}
.green {
  background-image: url("https://www.hiboucoop-staging.org/wbo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/green.gif");
}
.grey {
  background-image: url("https://www.hiboucoop-staging.org/wbo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/gray.gif");
}
.red {
  background-image: url("https://www.hiboucoop-staging.org/wbo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/red.gif");
}
.yellow {
  background-image: url("https://www.hiboucoop-staging.org/wbo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/yellow.gif");
}
.topright {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.bottomleft {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.bottomright {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.column1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.column2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.column3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
.column4 {
  grid-column: 4;
}
.column5 {
  grid-column: 5;
}
.column6 {
  grid-column: 6;
}
.column7 {
  grid-column: 7;
}
.column8 {
  grid-column: 8;
}
.column9 {
  grid-column: 9;
}
.column10 {
  grid-column: 10;
}
.column11 {
  grid-column: 11;
}
.column12 {
  grid-column: 12;
}
.column13 {
  grid-column: 13;
}
.column14 {
  grid-column: 14;
}
.column15 {
  grid-column: 15;
}
.top .row1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  animation: slideupdown 2s 0.2s backwards;
}
.top .row2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  animation: slideleftright 2s backwards;
}
.top .row3 {
  grid-row: 3;
  animation: sliderightleft 2s backwards;
}
@keyframes slideupdown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-176px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slidedownup {
  from {
    transform: translateY(176px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideleftright {
  from {
    transform: translateX(850px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes sliderightleft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-850px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
      <div class="top">
         <div class="triangle topleft green tt01 column1 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle topright blue tt02 column2 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft yellow column3 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright blue column3 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft red column4 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft grey column4 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft green column5 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft yellow column6 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft red column6 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft green column7 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright grey column7 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft blue column7 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle topright blue column8 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft yellow column8 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright grey column8 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle topright grey column8 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft red column8 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft yellow column9 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft red column9 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright blue column9 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft green column9 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright green column9 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft yellow column10 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright red column10 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft green column10 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright grey column10 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft blue column10 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft yellow column11 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft yellow column11 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright grey column11 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft red column11 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright grey column11 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft green column12 row1"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft blue column12 row2"></div>
         <div class="triangle topleft green column12 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright grey column12 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft grey column13 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomright blue column14 row3"></div>
         <div class="triangle bottomleft red column15 row3"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

https://codepen.io/RiccioBastardo/pen/mdJPVyg

Comment: Hey @leo-riccio, it would be great if you shared a code snippet. That way it would make it easier for other users to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is hard to answer. BUT I think the reason this is happening is because `transform` is being overwritten in the animation.

Here is simple working example:

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

```css
.triangle {
  border: 20px transparent solid;
  border-right-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(1000px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

[EDIT] Here are my suggestions after the author shared the code.

Basically, you are declaring `transform` more than once for a given element. in CSS the last occurrence overrides all previous occurrences. In order to solve this, you need to work around this. There is four ways you can do this:

1. Convert

```html
<div class="triangle topleft green column7 row2"></div>
```

to something like

```html
<div class="triangle-holder topleft column7 row2">
    <div class="triangle green"></div>
</div>
```

This allows you to have two different transforms on two different elements without overriding each other (as what's happening in the original code) The `transform: rotate()` is applied to `.triangle`, while `transform: translate()` is applied to `.triangle-holder`

2. Get rid of  `transform: rotate()` completely (as well as the background image), by using borders (see above for an example). This will **only** work for 90 degree rotations
3. Get rid of `transform: translate()` and use margin or top/left for positioning.
4. Animate each triangle explicitly in order to combine your transforms into one transformation.

I would recommend the second option, as it requires minimal changes to your code, and AFAIK is browser compatible way of creating CSS triangles.

Comment: The problem with approch is that the rotation would be the same for the entire row, while I need the rotation to be different for every triangle.

Comment: @LeoRiccio I just saw your updated code. The "problem" is the same as I mentioned  previously. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks, the first way was perfect. I started with borders but I had difficulties with making the entire thing relative to the width of the screen, so I opted for images.